# How to shorten the condition code ? (JAV, Check null)

Tags: java

I use it to check for null.DataSet has a structure of both String Integer and Bigdecimal data types.
How to shorten the condition code? Is there any way? To shorten my code. Thank you.

```
public void ConfrimData(DataSet data) {
            if (StringUtils.isEmpty(data.getA())
                || StringUtils.isEmpty(data.getB())
                || StringUtils.isEmpty(data.getC())
                || StringUtils.isEmpty(data.getD())
                || StringUtils.isEmpty(data.getE())
                || StringUtils.isEmpty(data.getF())
                ){
        if (StringUtils.isEmpty(data.getA())) {
            loggerTransaction.info(Var.VALUE_A);
        }
        if (StringUtils.isEmpty(data.getB())) {
            loggerTransaction.info(Var.VALUE_B);
        }
        if (StringUtils.isEmpty(data.getC())) {
            loggerTransaction.info(Var.VALUE_C);
        }
        if (StringUtils.isEmpty(data.getD())) {
            loggerTransaction.info(Var.VALUE_D);
        }
        if (StringUtils.isEmpty(data.getE())) {
            loggerTransaction.info(Var.VALUE_E);
        }
        if (StringUtils.isEmpty(data.getF())) {
            loggerTransaction.info(Var.VALUE_F);
        }
        return; 
        }
```

_**************DataSet**************

```
private String A = null;

private Integer B = null;

private String C= null;

private String D = null;

private BigDecimal E= null;

private String F= null;
```

Comment: why do the initial `if` ?

Comment: Apparently ... so that he can `return` if *any* of the conditions is true.

Comment: I will check all the values first. Next come check and print  one by one to see what values are null.

Comment: I don't think there is a good way to shorten this code ... assuming that you want it to behave the same way as the code currently does.  (I'd be asking myself if this `null` checking and logging and the `return` are actually a "band aid" solution for a deeper problem.)

Comment: I return because I will not continue to work in other areas . I will just look at the value null.

Comment: Okey. thank you sir.

Answer (score 2):

In your first if statement you check all the parameters to see if any of them are empty.
Then, in the inner if statements, you check them again. The first check is redundant. The return statement is also not necessary since it does not end the method early or returns any data.

Here is a shorter version that should give the same result:

```
public void confirmData(DataSet data) {
    if (StringUtils.isEmpty(data.getA())) {
        loggerTransaction.info(Var.VALUE_A);
    }
    if (StringUtils.isEmpty(data.getB())) {
        loggerTransaction.info(Var.VALUE_B);
    }
    if (StringUtils.isEmpty(data.getC())) {
        loggerTransaction.info(Var.VALUE_C);
    }
    if (StringUtils.isEmpty(data.getD())) {
        loggerTransaction.info(Var.VALUE_D);
    }
    if (StringUtils.isEmpty(data.getE())) {
        loggerTransaction.info(Var.VALUE_E);
    }
    if (StringUtils.isEmpty(data.getF())) {
        loggerTransaction.info(Var.VALUE_F);
    }
}
```

**EDIT**

Here is a slightly prettier solution with less code repetition:

```
public void confirmData(DataSet data) {
    logIfEmpty(data.getA(), Var.VALUE_A);
    logIfEmpty(data.getB(), Var.VALUE_B);
    logIfEmpty(data.getC(), Var.VALUE_C);
    logIfEmpty(data.getD(), Var.VALUE_D);
    logIfEmpty(data.getE(), Var.VALUE_E);
    logIfEmpty(data.getF(), Var.VALUE_F);
}
private void logIfEmpty(Object check, String log) {
    if (StringUtils.isEmpty(check)) {
        loggerTransaction.info(log);
    }
}
```

**EDIT #2**

And if you have other code you want to execute if you did *not* find any empty values, you can do this:

```
public void confirmData(DataSet data) {
    boolean foundEmpty;
    foundEmpty = logIfEmpty(data.getA(), Var.VALUE_A);
    foundEmpty = logIfEmpty(data.getB(), Var.VALUE_B) || foundEmpty;
    foundEmpty = logIfEmpty(data.getC(), Var.VALUE_C) || foundEmpty;
    foundEmpty = logIfEmpty(data.getD(), Var.VALUE_D) || foundEmpty;
    foundEmpty = logIfEmpty(data.getE(), Var.VALUE_E) || foundEmpty;
    foundEmpty = logIfEmpty(data.getF(), Var.VALUE_F) || foundEmpty;
    if(foundEmpty) {
        return;
    }
}
private boolean logIfEmpty(String check, String log) {
    if (StringUtils.isEmpty(check)) {
        loggerTransaction.info(log);
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Well, you could make it slightly less repeaty using streams, but it won't make it necessarily better, let alone faster:

```java
LinkedHashMap<Supplier, String> map = new LinkedHashMap<>();
map.put(data::getA, Var.VALUE_A);
map.put(data::getB, Var.VALUE_B);
map.put(data::getC, Var.VALUE_C);
map.put(data::getD, Var.VALUE_D);
map.put(data::getE, Var.VALUE_E);
map.put(data::getF, Var.VALUE_F);

List<String> logMessages = map.entrySet().stream()
    .filter(entry -> StringUtils.isEmpty(entry.getKey().get()))
    .map(Map.Entry::getValue)
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
if (!logMessages.isEmpty()) {
    logMessages.forEach(loggerTransaction::info);
}
else {
    // Remaining code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe assigning a flag...

```
public void ConfrimData(DataSet data) {
        boolean flag;
        if (flag = StringUtils.isEmpty(data.getA())) {
            loggerTransaction.info(Var.VALUE_A);
        }
        if (flag = StringUtils.isEmpty(data.getB()) || flag) {
            loggerTransaction.info(Var.VALUE_B);
        }
        if (flag = StringUtils.isEmpty(data.getC()) || flag) {
            loggerTransaction.info(Var.VALUE_C);
        }
        if (flag = StringUtils.isEmpty(data.getD()) || flag) {
            loggerTransaction.info(Var.VALUE_D);
        }
        if (flag = StringUtils.isEmpty(data.getE()) || flag) {
            loggerTransaction.info(Var.VALUE_E);
        }
        if (flag = StringUtils.isEmpty(data.getF()) || flag) {
            loggerTransaction.info(Var.VALUE_F);
        }
        if (flag) return;
```